# Почему поиск максимального значения в массиве происходит неверно: вместо 10 выводится 7?

Tags: java, массивы, max

Задача следующая:

> Пользователь вводит значение в массив и исходя из его значений выводится максимальное значение:

Мой код:

```java
public class max_number{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a;
        int n;
        int max3 = arr[0];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Сколько будет значений?");
        n = in.nextInt();
        a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++){
            System.out.println("Выведи значение для" + i + ": ");
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
            if (arr[i] > max3){
               max3 = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max3);
    }
}
```

Фактический результат сейчас:
Пользователь указывает, что в массиве будет 3 значения: `5`, `7`, `10`.
Максимальное значение сейчас выводит `7`, а ожидаемое - `10`:

[image: Вывод в терминале]

Comment: Ну классная задача, неплохое решение, что ещё сказать...

Comment: (На всякий случай поясню: К вопрос "не работает" желательно добавлять ошибку, желаемое поведение и текущее поведение, что бы люди хотя бы понимали где именно помогать)

Comment: А что такое arr?

Comment: Код, представленный в вопросе, вообще не будет компилироваться из-за путаницы с названиями переменных `a` и `arr`, и из=за обращения к элементу массива `arr[0]`, который не был проинициализирован.  Массив не нужен для решения задачи поиска максимума среди `n` введённых чисел.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, указанная в заголовке вопроса: `Почему поиск максимального значения в массиве происходит неверно: вместо 10 выводится 7?` НЕ воспроизводится из-за ошибок в коде, которые необходимо исправить:

1. Ошибки при объявлении переменных.
   В "классическом" стиле программирования требовалось сначала *объявить* переменные, и только затем заниматься действиями с ними, включая инициализацию.  В данном случае это привело к путанице с именем массива.
   Чтобы избежать таких ошибок, достаточно объявлять переменные непосредственно при присваивании их значений, чтобы не было лишнего кода между объявлением и присваиванием.  Также следует определиться с названием массива.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Сколько будет значений?");
int n = in.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[n];
// ...
```

2. Инициализация максимума.
   В исходном коде максимум инициализируется первым членом массива *до того как массив был создан.*  Но даже если непустой массив был создан правильно, он будет содержать нули, и соответственно максимуму будет присвоено значение 0, что приведёт к неправильному решению, если при вводе массив будет заполнен только отрицательными значениями.

В своём ответе Зонтик проинициализировал максимум *наименьшим* целочисленным значением `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, что вполне приемлемо для заведомо непустого массива.

Однако следует учесть, что `n = 0` является вполне допустимым размером массива, тогда он будет пустой, и максимум как таковой вообще не будет существовать.
То есть, имеет смысл объявить переменную для хранения максимума так:

```java
Integer max = null;
```

Также для поиска максимума можно использовать стандартный метод `Math.max`, с проверкой текущего максимума:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Введи значение для " + i + ": ");
    arr[i] = in.nextInt();
            
    max = Math.max(arr[i], max == null ? Integer.MIN_VALUE : max);
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Такое решение корректно обработает ситуации для *корректной* длины массива (неотрицательного числа), и найдёт максимум для любых элементов массива.

В случае неправильного ввода / отрицательной величины массива будут выброшены соответствующие непроверяемые исключения.

---

Однако даже исправленное решение представляет собой "монолит", где один метод отвечает за ввод данных, их обработку (поиск максимума) и вывод результата.

Поэтому имеет смысл улучшить приведённое решение, разбив исходную задачу на подзадачи при помощи отдельных методов, чтобы каждый из них отвечал за своё действие:

1. создаёт входной массив целых чисел (при помощи сканера потока ввода)
2. ищет максимум в массиве
3. объединяет вызовы двух вышеупомянутых методов и выводит результаты.

Исправленное решение можно представить в виде отдельного класса `FindMax` и класса-драйвера `Main`:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        new FindMax().execute();
    }
}
```

Код станет более структурированным:

```java
public class FindMax {
    public void execute() {
        int[] arr = inputArray();
        System.out.println("Введён массив: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
        Integer max = findMax(arr);
        System.out.println(max);
    }
    
    protected int[] inputArray() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите размер массива: ");
        
        int[] arr = new int[in.nextInt()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        
        return arr;
    }
    
    protected Integer findMax(int ... arr) {
        Integer max = null;
        for (int x : arr) {
            max = null == max ? x : Math.max(x, max.intValue());
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Такая организация кода (см. [шаблонный метод](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/template-method/java/example)) позволит в дальнейшем переопределить реализации методов как ввода, так и поиска максимума, например с помощью Stream API код можно значительно сократить:

```java
class FindMaxStream extends FindMax {
    protected int[] inputArray() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите размер массива: ");
        
        return IntStream.generate(in::nextInt).limit(in.nextInt()).toArray();
    }
    
    protected Integer findMax(int ... arr) {
        OptionalInt max = Arrays.stream(arr).max(); 
        return max.isPresent() ? max.getAsInt() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте попробуем составить алгоритм действий и в то же время пройтись по вашему коду, проверяя, все ли пункты правильно выполнены и нет ли ничего лишнего.

1. Получаем от пользователя количество чисел и инициализируем массив, предварительно проверяя, что длинна массива не меньше 1.

Ваши ошибки на этом шаге:

- Массива почему-то 2: `a` и `arr`. Нужен только один. Пусть это будет `array`.
- Переменные лучше называть говорящими и понятными именами. Поэтому `in` лучше заменить на `Scanner`, а `n` например на `length`.
- Нужно проверить, что пользователь ввёл корректную длину массива (то есть не 0 и не отрицательное число). Можно сделать так, что программа не пойдёт дальше, пока число не будет правильным.

Тогда код из этого пункта алгоритма будет такой:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int length = 1;
while(true){
    System.out.println("Сколько будет значений?");
    length = scanner.nextInt();
    if(length < 1) System.err.println("Длинна массива не может быть " + length + "!");
    else break;

}
int[] array = new int[length];
```

3. Объявляем переменную и приравниваем её минимальному значению типа `int`. Здесь у меня вопрос: почему у вас переменная называется `max3`? Почему не просто `max` (а лучше бы `maxNumber`)?

Минимальное значение типа `int` удобно взять из константы `MIN_VALUE` класса `Integer`:

```java
int maxNumber = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

3. Получаем числа от пользователя. На этом этапе ошибка одна: эти размножающиеся массивы. Массив нужен только один. Реализация этого пункта алгоритма может выглядеть так:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Введи следующий индекс массива:");
    array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

4. Собственно ищем максимум (в том же самом цикле, где просили вводить пользователя числа). Это реализовано у вас правильно, но можно записать `if` короче:

```java
if(array[i] > maxNumber) maxNumber = array[i];
```

5. Выводим максимум на экран.

**P.S**: прошу внимательно прочитать ответ и понять все ошибки. Тогда вы без труда склеите приведённые лоскутки кода в единое целое.

Comment: Строго говоря, 0 -- вполне допустимый размер массива :)  К тому же успели отредактировать ввод элементов массива с помощью цикла `foreach`

Comment: @NowhereMan искать максимальное число в пустом массиве как-то странно :) А на счёт foreach - в данном случае он не очень подходит, так как не получится присваивать значение элементу массива (то есть `i = scanner.nextInt()` не прокатит, значение же будет присваиваться `i`, а не `array[i]`).

Comment: Для простоты / базового уровня можно  считать что массив не пустой.  Для представления максимума из пустого массива/коллекции _в общем случае_ следует пользоваться `Optional` / `OptionalInt` (как собственно и сделано в Stream API) либо старым добрым `null`.

Answer (score -2):

Ну начнём с того, что у вас переменная называется то `arr`, то `a`... Буд то не вы вовсе код писали)
Да и запустить его не получится

Заметим, что вы выполняете

```java
int max3 = arr[0];
```

ещё до того, как arr был проинициализирован. Перенесём эту строку ниже

Вот что получается:

```java
public class max_number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr;
        int n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Сколько будет значений?");
        n = in.nextInt();
        arr = new int[n];
        int max3 = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.println("Выведи значение для" + i + ": ");
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
            if (arr[i] > max3){
               max3 = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max3);
    }
}
```

После небольшого изучения кода заметим, что массив используется только для хранения **текущего** значения, а значит мы его можно просто поменять на обычную переменную

Предполагаю что изначально был запланирован следующий алгоритм:

1. Создаём массив длины `n`
2. Проходимся по каждому элементу массива и вписывает в него введённое пользователем значение
3. Проходимся по каждому элемент массива и ищем наибольшее
4. Выводим его

В данном контексте массив будет полезнее, так как в будущем мы сможем передавать **любой** массив.

Однако в данном конкретном случае он вообще никак не используется, и по сути алгоритм такой:

1. Проходимся в массиве от `0` до `n`

   1. Запрашиваем число от пользователя
   2. Если число больше текущего максимального, то меняем максимальное на текущее
2. Выводим результат

Как мы видим массив нам и не нужен, и код легко можно переписать на такой:

```java
public class max_number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Сколько будет значений?");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int max = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.println("Выведи значение для " + i + ": ");
            int currentValue = in.nextInt();
            if (currentValue > max){
               max = currentValue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Данный код успешно работает с положительными числами. Однако если мы введём отрицательное, то максимальное будет равно нулю. Есть простых способа решить эту проблему:

1. Задать `min` на минимальное допустимое число для типа `int`
2. Задавать `min` первым введённым числом

Мы будем решать через второй вариант.
Вынесем первую итерацию цикла из цикла:

```java
System.out.println("Выведи значение для " + 0 + ": ");
int max = in.nextInt();
```

И следовательно уберём первую итерацию из самого цикла:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {...}
```

Финальный код:

```java
public class max_number {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Сколько будет значений?");
        int n = in.nextInt();
        
        // Итерация 0:
        System.out.println("Выведи значение для " + 0 + ": ");
        int max = in.nextInt();
        
        // Итерации 1..n:
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            System.out.println("Выведи значение для " + i + ": ");
            int currentValue = in.nextInt();
            if (currentValue > max){
               max = currentValue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Объясняю минус: все решения в данном коде содержат баги из-за предположений о непустоте массива (у пустого массива нет максимума), и о том, что введенные числа будут содержать хотя бы одно неотрицательное значение.